# How do I include vibration in my keypad design

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, keypad

I am working on a project that includes the use of a Keypad. I intend to include a beep sound with a soft vibration when a key is pressed. I am yet to figure out how to generate such vibrations.

I need your suggestions.

Comment: Plenty of information is available via Google. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

A quick lookup on Google would have given you results for "vibration motors". Those are brushed DC motors which have an unevenly distributed load on the shaft, which means the motor generates vibrations when it turns (of frequency proportional to the shaft speed).

Comment: ..also search on 'haptic'.